# How do I override an attr_accessor getter from a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, ruby-2.0

```
module HasUrl
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_accessor :bar
  end

  def bar
    0
  end
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include HasUrl
end
```

The bar attribute is not stored in the database, but it is used in a form (using SimpleForm's `f.input`). I'd like to override the getter for this method so I can set `bar` based on other attributes and have the form properly pre-fill the value.

The problem is that using `attr_accessor` in an included block like this will setup the getter on the `Foo` class. Because the module is included above `Foo` in the ancestor chain, the custom `bar` method that returns 0 is never touched.

One way to solve this is

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include HasUrl

  def bar
    super
  end
end
```

But I want to avoid this extra step. I just want to include the module and have it just "work". Another option is to use different helpers in my form (f.input_field etc) but then I cannot take advantage of SimpleForm's wrappers.

Module#prepend will not solve my problems either, since `HasUrl` also defines some other things (notably an ActiveRecord callback). If I prepend, these callbacks cause errors:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `_run_...__find__...__callbacks`
```

Is there a way to get around this error so that prepend can work? Or another way to do this altogether?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure you want the `attr_accessor`? Wouldn't an `attr_writer` suffice?

```
require 'active_support/all'

module HasUrl
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_writer :bar
  end

  def bar
    0
  end
end

class Foo
  include HasUrl
end

p Foo.new.bar
```

Anyhow, if you really want to use `attr_accessor`, this should work:

```
require 'active_support/all'

module HasUrl
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_accessor :bar
    define_method :bar do
      0
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include HasUrl
end

p Foo.new.bar
```

Comment: That's right, if you overwrite the getter then using `attr_writer` will be enough

Comment: Thank you. I had gone with `attr_writer` before but it was causing problems with my form. This is because I had two attributes on the `attr_accessor` line and one of them I did need the getter. I was just being stupid when reading the error message. Also, it seems like the prepend issue was fixed in p195: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10899 so that would work as well (I am working on p0).